# How to do aggregation and group in a sub field of mongodb which is an array?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, rest

I am building a API for check in and check out of employees for attendance system. For each employee I need to sum total hours worked in a month and then a year. I tried using aggregation, project and group but I am not getting the total hours of employee in month or year.

My portion of schema looks like this:

```
const EmployeeSchema = new Schema({
_id: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
attendance: [{
    date: {type: Date, default: Date.now},
    entry: {type: Date, required: false},
    exit: { 
        time: {type: Date, required: false}
     },
    totalHours: {type: Number, required: false}
}]
```

)}

For aggregating, I tried to implement this way:

```
exports.aggregation = (req, res) => {
const id = req.params.salespersonId;
DailySalesPerson.aggregate([
      {$unwind: "$attendance"}, 
      {
          $group: {
              _id: {
                  month: {"$month":"$attendance.date"}
              },
              totalHours: {$sum: "totalHours"},
              count: {$sum: 1}
          }
      },


])
.then(result => {
    res.status(200).json({result});
})
```

};

I did not get the total hours counted of employee per month or year.

**Now  my result looks like this:**

```
{
    "result": [
    {
        "_id": "5c5bb13c1d92482b148ed17b",
        "attendance": [
            {
                "date": "2019-02-07T04:30:07.391Z",
                "totalHours": 1,
                "month": 2,
                "year": 2019
            },
            {
                "date": "2019-02-07T04:51:05.359Z",
                "totalHours": 1,
                "month": 2,
                "year": 2019
            },
            {
                "date": "2019-02-07T04:56:21.951Z",
                "totalHours": 1,
                "month": 2,
                "year": 2019
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "_id": "5c5fdb1781165a1e58115da7",
        "attendance": []
    },
    {
        "_id": "5c5fdd1738ec411b1849ce58",
        "attendance": [
            {
                "date": "2019-02-10T08:14:01.201Z",
                "totalHours": 1,
                "month": 2,
                "year": 2019
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "_id": "5c5fdf6336e9ea24e0e69795",
        "attendance": [
            {
                "date": "2019-02-10T08:23:14.180Z",
                "totalHours": 1,
                "month": 2,
                "year": 2019
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

}

I need to aggregate each person's total hours worked per month and per year. Now my results look like as above. How to I sum total hours of each day?

Comment: Could you post the sample collection and the output

Comment: I only get month and year grouped in array and no output for total hours @AnthonyWinzlet

Comment: It will help us to generate the output if you post the sample collection and the output

Comment: @AnthonyWinzlet I have edited how my result looks like now or collection. I need to agrregate attendance by months, and sum total hours per month.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use below aggregation

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  { "$project": {
    "totalHoursInThisMonth": {
      { "$let": {
        "vars": { "date": {
          "$filter": {
            "input": "$attendance",
            "as": "attend",
            "cond": {
              "$and": [
                { "$gte": ["$$attend.date", startOfMonth] },
                { "$lte": ["$$attend.date", endOfMonth] }
              ]
            }
          }
        }},
        "in": "$$date.totalHours"
      }}
    }
  }}
])
```

Answer (score 0):

**I used this and worked :** I got totall hours worked per month, year and days count

```
exports.aggregationHours = (req, res) => {
let id = req.params.salespersonId;
id= mongoose.Types.ObjectId(id);
DailySalesPerson.aggregate([ 
    {"$match":{
        _id: id
    }},
      {$unwind: "$attendance"}, 
      {
          $group: {
              _id: {
                  month: {"$month":"$attendance.date"},
                  year: {"$year":"$attendance.date"}
              },
              totalHours: {$sum: "$attendance.totalHours"},
                daysworkedCount: {$sum: 1}
          }
      },  
])
.then(result => {
    res.status(200).json({result});
})
```

};